# No way to login with stack exchange on askubuntu.com?

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

I just noticed that I'm not logged in on askubuntu.com and here's my login page:

[image]

What do I click to just use my connected StackExchange account?

Comment: +1, agree it's bad user experience that should be changed. We should not be forced to guess "hey, those text boxes are for Stack Exchange account"

Answer (score 8):

Type your Stack Exchange credentials in the email and password fields, then click the blue login button.

[image]

Comment: Silly me! I just got lost in those login options - I think I used to have to pick the way I log in first and then see the two boxes before. Anyway, thanks ;)

Comment: No problem @d33tah, I've done the exact same thing before ;)